# GroovyShell - Error when splitting a script in two parts (MissingMethodExceptionNoStack)

Tags: java, groovy, groovyshell

I'm totally new to Groovy, so I hope the answer is not obvious...

Let's say I have a script "Test.groovy":

```
class A {
    def greet() {println "Hey there!"}
}

new A().greet()
```

And I evaluate this script with `GroovyShell` (from Java):

```
new GroovyShell().evaluate(new File("Test.groovy"));
```

I get the expected output:

> Hey there!

Now, I remove the last line from the script, and instead evaluate it in a separate call to `evaluate()`, I get a pretty obscure exception.

"Test.groovy":

```
class A {
    def greet() {println "Hey there!"}
}
```

Java:

```
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell();
shell.evaluate(new File("Test.groovy"));
shell.evaluate("new A().greet()");
```

> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MissingMethodExceptionNoStack: No signature of method: A.main() is applicable for argument types: ([Ljava.lang.String;) values: [[]]
>   Possible solutions: wait(), wait(long), any(), find(), wait(long, int), each(groovy.lang.Closure)

Even funnier, if I let the script as it was and change only the Java part, it works perfectly (I get two "Hey there!")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should help explain what you're seeing: http://www.groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_script_class

Groovy regarded your first .groovy file as a script because that last line existed outside of a class declaration. Groovy compiles into Java byte code, and Java requires that all code be defined within a class. To comply, Groovy did some magic and dynamically translated your script into a Java class with a `main` method--something akin to this:

```
public class script1440427072752 extends groovy.lang.Script { 

    public script1440427072752() {
    }

    public script1440427072752(groovy.lang.Binding context) {
        super(context)
    }

    public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) {
        org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.runScript(script1440427072752, args)
    }

    public java.lang.Object run() {
        new A().greet()
    }

}
public class A extends java.lang.Object { 

    public java.lang.Object greet() {
        this.println('Hey there!')
    }

}
```

When you removed that line, however Groovy regarded your .groovy file as a typical Java class named `A`. No dynamic translation into `groovy.lang.Script` required.

When you attempted to execute `A`, GroovyShell looked for a `main` method, couldn't find one, and threw that error.